# Autodesk Construction Cloud - ISSUE API to update with Visibility Control

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk-construction-cloud

Autodesk Construction Cloud API - I want to update existing Issue with Visibility control. i.e:  Isolate 2 Clashed Items programitically. then Update Issue.
This is the existing Issue.Clash.

[image: The existing Issue]

This is what I want to update Issue automatically. Assume we already have Clashed Item list.
[image: Isolate elements and updat issue]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to 'Isolate 2 items' & Create Issue with API.

[image]

Comment: The question and answer are unclear. Code should not be posted as images but as text.